# Changing the color of a row in list control in mfc on double click

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have a list control `CListCtrl`  named  `m_listCtrl` which displays `ID` , `Firstname` and `Lastname` when the dialogbox is created. In the code below I handle a `double click` by getting the `position` of the item clicked and changing the value of the first column of that row.

```
//This is in the message map and IDC_LISTNAMES is the list control
ON_NOTIFY(NM_DBLCLK, IDC_LISTNAMES,  OnDoubleClick)


void CSqlMfcTestDlg::OnDoubleClick(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
{

  POSITION pos = m_listCtrl.GetFirstSelectedItemPosition();
  if (pos == NULL)
  {
    TRACE(_T("No items were selected!\n"));
  }
  else
  {
    while (pos)
    {
        int nItem = m_listCtrl.GetNextSelectedItem(pos);

        itemClicked = nItem;
        CString idString = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(nItem, 0);
        CString textString = m_listCtrl.GetItemText(nItem, 1);
        MessageBox(L"Item Clicked is : " + textString);
        m_listCtrl.SetItemText(nItem,0, idString+L"(Clicked)");


    }
  }

}
```

instead of  `m_listCtrl.SetItemText(nItem,0, idString+L"(Clicked)");` I would like to add a statement to change the color of that row.

Comment: Your code says `OnDoubleClick()' is a dialog handler. Try it on the ListCtrl object.

Comment: I have a dialog in which there is a list control, I have set `m_listCtrl` style as 
 `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(m_listCtrl, LVS_EX_GRIDLINES|LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);` The code works fine but instead of changing the value in the list control, I wanted to find a way to change the color of that row

Comment: Now declare m_listCtrl as MyListCtrl, where MyListCtrl is a class derived from CListctrl. After that add new message handlers for MyListCtrl. Your current code will only intercept double clicks on the dialog control.

Comment: The row changes color if selected. Add `m_listCtrl.ModifyStyle(0, LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS);` in `OnInitDialog`, so that the selection is always visible. Or do you want to change to custom color?

Comment: The context is, on clicking an item in the list control, I want to add a note and to show that the note is added, I want to change the color of that row. It should persist in the sense that when I reopen the application, I still want the rows with a note to be the color I set. I tried looking online for this but did not find much

Comment: The note is not displayed as a column in the list control, the color of that row indicates that a note is present and on double click I will fetch as display the note. But I can't figure out how to set row color.

Comment: @seccpur Notification messages like `NM_DBLCLK` are normally handled by the parent window (unless you use message reflection), so the code shown by OP basically is correct.

Comment: Why don't you use `CMFCListCtrl`and its own method `OnGetCellBkColor` which is way easier than Custom Drawing?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!!

Answer (score 0):

See this snippet:

```
class MyListCtrl: public CListCtrl
{
   private:
      int m_row;
   public:
      afx_msg void OnNMDblclk(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult); // write your custom code in the definition
      afx void OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult);
}; 

class CSqlMfcTestDlg: public CDialogEx 
{
   private:
      MyListCtrl m_listCtrl;    
};
```

Definitions ( not tested):

```
void MyListCtrl::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
  LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW  lplvcd = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)pNMHDR;
  int iRow = lplvcd->nmcd.dwItemSpec;

  switch(lplvcd->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
  {
     case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_PREPAINT | CDDS_ITEM:
    {
         if(iRow == m_row)
         lplvcd->clrTextBk =  RGB(0,0,255);
    }
  }
}
void MyListCtrl::OnNMDblclk(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
    m_row = GetSelectionMark();
    RedrawItems(m_row, m_row);
}
```

Comment: You can catch listview's double click messages the way it is shown in the question. If you do this in `CListCtrl` it needs `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT` message handler.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Noted , thanks. OP wants to change color of the selected row, so custom draw should be easier.

Comment: The required message map entries should be shown (`BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`, `END_MESSAGE_MAP`).